# Mobile view of footer div makes Social Media Icons display vertically along with some text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been working on a bootstrap website and when swapped to mobile view my footer Images stack vertically out of the div. The code and example image are attached.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootstrap test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers' rel='stylesheet'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JavaScript/index.js" defer></script>
    </head>




    <body>          
        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top transparent sticky-top" id="navbar">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="images/DallE_Extendo-removebg.png" width="80" height="60" alt="">
                </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--NavBar Ends-->


        <!--Content Begins-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0;">
              <img src="images/Charlie-Co.-Barbershop-West-Chester-3.png" class="img" width="100">
              <a href="#" class="carousel-caption">Book now through booksy!</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 border-right border-bottom border-dark" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
              <h1 style="text-align: center; text-decoration: underline;">#</h1>
              <h1>Opening hours</h1>
              <p>Hours could change depending on Holidays & Bank Holidays</p>
              <table> 
                <tr class="monday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Monday</span></td>
                    <td>9:30 - 18:30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="tuesday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Tuesday</span></td>
                    <td>9:30 - 18:30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="wednesday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Wednesday</span></td>
                    <td>9:30 - 18:30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="thursday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Thursday</span></td>
                    <td>9:30 - 19:00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="friday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Friday</span></td>
                    <td>9:30 - 19:00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="saturday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Saturday</span></td>
                    <td>9:00 - 18:00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sunday fvl-d">
                    <td><span>Sunday</span></td>
                    <td>11:00 - 15:30</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 border-left border-bottom border-dark" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non ultricies velit, eget suscipit velit. Nam laoreet magna ornare ex ornare ultrices. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean vel tincidunt velit. Nam sed est metus. Maecenas commodo dolor non lorem semper malesuada. Aliquam tempor blandit sapien in sodales. Integer eu metus efficitur ligula mattis pretium. Donec finibus mi non sodales condimentum. Donec elementum nunc quis mauris pulvinar porta. Sed sed est eget justo vestibulum malesuada vitae at nulla. Suspendisse quis efficitur lorem. Phasellus non ornare ante. Mauris ullamcorper, ligula in malesuada malesuada, purus nibh pretium dui, ac eleifend purus mauris vel nisi. Sed lacinia hendrerit magna at pharetra. Suspendisse quis varius diam, et ultricies dui. In scelerisque felis ac sapien bibendum, eget iaculis nisl egestas. Proin tempor et magna eu molestie. Praesent consequat lorem ut accumsan vehicula. Nunc luctus turpis non sollicitudin fermentum. Fusce nec viverra ex, sit amet tristique turpis.</p>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="footer">
                <div class="col-md-1" style="font-size: 10px;">
                    <p>#</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 10%; text-align: center;">
                    <p>#</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5" id="sm" style="padding-left: 10%; padding-bottom: 1%;">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/rsz_1rsz_insta.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/rsz_twitter.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/rsz_1facebook-removebg-preview.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 5%; text-align: center;">
                    <p>#<br>#</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>


        <!--Content Ends-->
    </body>
       
</html>
```

CSS
/

```
* NavBar parameters*/




nav#navbar {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
  }
  
  
  
  
  nav#navbar ul.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  /* Image and text over image parameters */
  .img {
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 0;
  }
  
  
  
  
  /*#1 media settings for the text link to go to booksy*/
  
  
  
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
      /* Adjust font size for small screens */
      .carousel-caption {
          font-size: 1em !important;
          padding-bottom: 0;
  
  
  
  
      }
  }
  
  
  
  
  .carousel-caption{
      font-family: 'Bangers';
      font-size: 50px;
      color: gold;
  }
  
  
  
  
  .carousel-caption:hover{
      color: #00E2FF;
  }
  
  
  
  
  .col-md-12#footer{
    background-color: lightgray !important;
    height: 5em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Adjust font size for small screens */
    .col-md-12#footer {
        display: flex;
        padding-bottom: 0;

    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Adjust font size for small screens */
    .col-md-5#sm {
        size: 1px;
    }
}

  /*--------------*/
  
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

    #activerow {
        border: 0.5px solid gold;
    }

    #activerow > td {
        color: gold;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    #activerow > td > span {
        color: gold;
    }

    /* Table Design */
    .opening-hours {
        overflow: hidden;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
        background-color: white;
        padding: 1em;
        max-width: 450px;
        min-width: 320px;
    }


    .fvl-d > td {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 1.2px;
        color: #A299AC;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 1em;
    }

    .fvl-d > td > span {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 600;
        letter-spacing: 1.2px;
        color: #A299AC;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 382px) {

 .fvl-d > td {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 15px 5px;
    }

   #activerow {
        border: none;
        background-color: gold;
    }

    #activerow > td {
        color: white;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    #activerow > td > span {
        color: white;
    }

}
```

Any ideas you may have please let me know! Stuck on this bit as it stands but any other help would be unreal. Thanks in advance guys!

[Example of how it looks on mobile now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAPoj.png)

Comment: add **d-inline-flex** class in social media parent div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added display: flex; to the footer images div and it worked fine

code :

```
<div class="col-md-5" id="sm" style="padding-left: 10%; padding-bottom: 1%;display: flex;">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/rsz_1rsz_insta.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#"><img src="images/rsz_twitter.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#"><img src="images/rsz_1facebook-removebg-preview.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            </div>
```

Comment: Thats why he is the GOAT! Amine love it my guy thank you!

Comment: anytime ! thank you for the kind words :D

Comment: Quick question on that actually if you have time?  The div above it usually has text in it but enough to stack it vertically out of the footer. Any idea on a fix for that one?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understood it correctly, the div above this one has text and you want to place it out of the footer just in the top of it right?

Comment: So basically the div looks a bit like <p> Please come to here at this time and date etc. </p> and extends out past the footer div. Im trying to keep all the text within the div which is being a touch annoying to my brain XD
Thanks again for the help

Comment: try this 

p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

and use "title" in html to display the rest of the text when the user hover on it